# Mathematical rules for dimensional analysis

Tags: notation, dimensional-analysis, si-units

In dimensional analysis we treat the units as their own objects, in this case $1m$ is a unit multiplied by a number, and forms a 'quantity' is this explicitly the same object as the unit itself?

Having $1m=m$ implies that perhaps $-1m=-m$, I think it perhaps makes sense to make a distinction between the unit and the quantity, although $m$ could refer to a to a length, perhaps $'1m'$ is the length and we can show that $2m=2*(1m)$?
We would never give a length of $'m'$, the issue with this is then $2(1*m)$ = $2*m$ which seems to be an issue based on the definition of multiplication?

If we can have an object just called $m$ and it is defined under addition (in the case it's defined as $1*m$) then we must have an additive inverse and $-m$ should exist, how do we deal with this issue? $-m$ should make no sense in the context of the unit.

How about taking $0*m$ is $0*m=0*s$? I believe this is not the case, as dimension needs to be preserved in multiplication, but I'm not sure.

It doesn't seem all the rules of algebra apply to units so it causes me confusion.

Comment: _Can we have −m as −1∗m??_ Why to stop here ? Maybe you want _at least_ $[0^\circ..360^\circ]~m^\circ$ "degree-meters" for describing exact position vector ? So the answer is **no**, unit is a measuring type definition and should not depend on measurement direction. However quantity which it measures,- can depend on direction.

Comment: Worth reading if you want to do a deep dive into the algebra of dimensional analysis: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/12/29/a-mathematical-formalisation-of-dimensional-analysis/

Comment: 5m can be treated the same as 5x.  x is a variable that can be positive or negative.  Having a coefficient of 5 in front of that x does not change the character of the variable.  Accordingly, "m" is a unit of length all on its own, regardless of the coefficient in front of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one way to formalize things. As a warning, I would imagine most working physicists would consider this to be massive overkill, but it will provide a framework for answering your questions so we will press on. For the moment, let's consider only things with dimensions of mass, length, and time; the generalization to include other dimensions (e.g. temperature) is straightforward.

---

First, define a *physical dimension* as an element of $\langle a,b,c\rangle\in \mathbb Q^3$ - that is, an ordered triple of rational numbers. We identify $\langle 1,0,0\rangle $ with the dimension of mass, $\langle 0,1,0\rangle$ with the dimension of length, and $\langle 0,0,1\rangle $ with the dimension of time.  In (possibly) more familiar notation, we might write

$$\langle a,b,c\rangle \equiv [M]^a[L]^b [T]^c$$

The space of physical dimensions constitutes a (rational) vector space, which we call $\mathscr D$.  I emphasize that these objects are not *units* like kg or m/s, but rather dimensions such as mass or length per time. The "addition" operation for dimensions (which corresponds to the multiplication of physical quantities, see $(2)$ below) will be denoted $\star$, and defined as
$$\langle a,b,c\rangle \star \langle d,e,f\rangle := \langle a+d,b+e,c+f\rangle$$
The "scalar multiplication" operation for dimensions (which corresponds to the exponentiation of physical quantities, see $(3)$ below) is defined as
$$\langle a,b,c\rangle \wedge d := \langle d\cdot a,d\cdot b,d\cdot c\rangle$$

---

Next, a *physical quantity* is a pair $(x,D)$ where $x\in \mathbb R$ and $D\in \mathscr D$. Adopting the [SI system of units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units), we may make the following definitions:
$$\matrix{\mathrm{kg} \equiv \bigg(1,\langle 1,0,0\rangle\bigg)\\ \mathrm m \equiv \bigg(1,\langle0,1,0\rangle\bigg) \\ \mathrm s \equiv \bigg(1,\langle0,0,1\rangle\bigg)}$$

Physical quantities of the same dimension may be added together as follows:
$$(x,D) + (y,D) := (x+y,D)\tag{1}$$
Additionally, physical quantities of arbitrary dimension may be multiplied together:
$$(x,D_1) * (y,D_2) := (x\cdot y, D_1 \star D_2)\tag{2}$$
They can also be exponentiated:
$$(x,D)^y = (x^y, D\wedge y )\tag{3}$$

What we usually call *dimensionless* quantities are really quantities of the form $(x,\mathbf 0)$. We would ordinarily denote such a thing simply by $x\in \mathbb R$.

Finally, we may define derived units for convenience - for example,
$$ g \equiv 10^{-3} \mathrm kg \equiv \bigg(10^{-3}, \langle 1,0,0\rangle\bigg)$$
and so forth.

---

Having defined all of these rules, we can provide your questions with unambiguous answers.

> In dimensional analysis we treat the units as their own objects, in this case $1m$ is a unit multiplied by a number, and forms a 'quantity' is this explicitly the same object as the unit itself?

Physical units are just convenient choices of physical quantity such that we may express any other physical quantity by combining them via multiplication and exponentiation.  They are very much like a basis for a vector space in that way. In the formalism presented here, $1\ \mathrm m$ and $\mathrm m$ are the same thing because
$$1\ \mathrm m \equiv 1 * \bigg(1,\langle 0,1,0\rangle\bigg) = \bigg(1\cdot 1,\langle 0,1,0\rangle\bigg) = \bigg(1,\langle 0,1,0\rangle\bigg) \equiv \mathrm m$$

> Having $1m=m$ implies that perhaps $-1m=-m$

This is also true for the same reason, though we would never write the latter expression because it could easily lead to confusion.

> We would never give a length of "$m$"

True, but that's just a matter of convention and natural language.

> If we can have an object just called $m$ and it is defined under addition (in the case it's defined as $1*m$) then we must have an additive inverse and $-m$ should exist, how do we deal with this issue? $-m$ should make no sense in the context of the unit.

I don't understand your objection.  $-\mathrm m$ is a perfectly reasonable physical quantity (it might be a coordinate, for example), but to avoid awkwardness and misunderstandings we would pretty much always write that as $-1\ \mathrm m$.

> How about taking $0*m$ is $0∗m=0∗s$? I believe this is not the case, as dimension needs to be preserved in multiplication, but I'm not sure.

I would agree. Two physical quantities $(x,D_1)$ and $(y,D_2)$ are equal if $x=y$ and $D_1=D_2$. In particular, $0\ \mathrm m \neq 0\ \mathrm s$ because
$$0\ \mathrm m \equiv \bigg(0, \langle 0,1,0\rangle\bigg) \neq \bigg(0, \langle 0,0,1\rangle \bigg) \equiv 0\ \mathrm s$$

---

I'll conclude by demonstrating that $0.5$ m/s = $50$ cm/s using my formalism.  Note that

$$0.5\ \mathrm{m/s} \equiv \bigg(0.5,\langle 0,1,-1\rangle\bigg)$$
Next, $1\ \mathrm{cm} = 10^{-2}\ \mathrm{m} \equiv \big(10^{-2},\langle 0,1,0\rangle\big)$ and so $1 \ \mathrm{cm/s} = \big(10^{-2},\langle 0,1,-1\rangle\big)$.  Therefore, we have that

$$50 \ \mathrm{cm/s} \equiv 50*\bigg(10^{-2},\langle 0,1,-1\rangle\bigg) = \bigg(0.5,\langle 0,1,-1\rangle\bigg) \equiv 0.5\ \mathrm{m/s}$$

Comment: Awesome answer. Do you have any references for further reading?

Comment: @Shaktyai Andrew linked [this blog post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/12/29/a-mathematical-formalisation-of-dimensional-analysis/) by Terry Tao in a comment to the question; while my approach does not precisely align with either formalization which he describes explicitly, it is a phenomenal discussion.

Comment: @Shaktyai And thank you for the kind comment :)

Comment: Brilliant answer, so it is as I thought, I just find it strange that we can have $-m$ but I guess it's just one of those things

Comment: I guess when you try to formalize such a thing, you get answers that are required mathematically, but don't make physical sense

Comment: @user37577 Thanks! I’m still not entirely certain what you find unphysical, though - $-1\ \mathrm m$ means exactly the same thing as $-\mathrm m$, so if the former makes sense (which it does e.g. as a coordinate) then so does the latter, even if the latter is a slightly unconventional and weird thing to write. One might demand that by convention, we always write an explicit number before the unit symbol (so $1\ \mathrm$ rather than just $\mathrm m$) which would resolve your issue even though it’s a rule governing pen strokes more so than any actual mathematics.

Comment: @J.Murray I guess it's a case of 'if we have a meter, what is a minus-meter?' I would understand it that it's just a meter in the opposite direction, i.e. you could even think of 'scaling' the meter in a positive and 'scaling' the meter in a negative, either way it works.

Comment: @user37577 "what is a minus-meter" - well, try to remember how you felt when you first learned about negative numbers. The first instinct is to say "how can there be *a negative amount of something*"? But then you start to realize that numbers are this more abstract structure that can be mapped to different things: maybe -x represents a debt, or maybe its an instruction to take x steps back instead of forward. The same sort of abstraction happens here - maybe you have a coordinate system which establishes directions, and you're measuring directed lengths, or coordinates, or you're adding steps

Comment: "I guess when you try to formalize such a thing, you get answers that are required mathematically, but don't make physical sense" - No, this just tells you that units of length to not form a vector space. But they form a positive space. Each positive space can be extended to a unique (up to a natural isomorphism) 1-dim. oriented real vector space, that would be one way to interpret $-\mathrm m$...

Answer (score 2):

> It doesn't seem all the rules of algebra apply to units so it causes me confusion.

Indeed, units of length form a **positive space**, not a vector space. The space is closed under addition and the multiplication with positive numbers. See ["An Algebraic Approach to Physical Scales"](https://inspirehep.net/literature/1422662) for much more information.

Answer (score 0):

The measure of a physical quantity can be interpreted as the multiplication of a pure number, here $1$, and a unit of measurement, here $m$, that has the same physical dimension of the measured physical quantities. A $m$ indicates a length (and thus a physical quantity) of $1\,m$, like $2 \, m$ means twice that length.

When you write the length of $1 \, m$, I think that you can write $m$ implying that it's the same as $1 \, m$, but I wouldn't do it, while I'd explicitly write the pure number as well.

In **dimensional analysis** we don't care about the pure numbers, but only about the **physical dimensions**, each of which can have several different units of measurement: as an example a the physical dimension length $L$ can have several different units of measurement, like meters ($m$), millimetres ($mm$), inches ($in$), feet ($ft$),...

As an example, the dimensional analysis of the Newton's second principle of dynamics for a system with constant mass reads

$m \mathbf{a} = \mathbf{F}$,

and you need to check that $[m \mathbf{a}] = [\mathbf{F}]$, i.e.

$M \dfrac{L}{t^2} = F$,

given that:

- $M$ is the physical dimension of mass;
- $L/t^2$ is the physical dimension of acceleration, being $L$ the one for length, $t$ for time;
- $F$ is the physical dimension of force.

Comment: can we consider $1$ the number that returns the unit as an answer in multiplication then? Where as $2$ would give us something which is mathematically double in magnitude? I'm really asking if mathematically speaking they are definitely the same object.

Comment: yes, they are the same. I don't see any reason (besides philosophy arguments) that makes $1 m \ne m$, like I don't see any reason that makes $1 x \ne x$.

Comment: Because $x$ is a number, the fact that they are the same is well defined, it's best not to assume anything as they are units but we treat them like variables.

Comment: $x$ could be more than a pure number. Think at the second law of Dynamics, $m \mathbf{a} = \matfbf{F}$, no symbol represents a pure number here

Comment: @user37577 You can think of *m* as being an unspecified constant (a number), and then you can scale that (resize it *s* times by multiplying it by a scalar *s*, to get *sm*: 0.5 *m*, 2 *m*, 100 *m*, ...). So, if I wanted to know how long is 2 *m*, you could give me something that you know represents the length *m* - like some stick (some standard), and I can use *any* measuring device using *any* units whatsoever to measure the stick, and then multiply whatever I got by 2 to get the correct length. That's what 2 *m* *means*.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović if we define $-m$ (which we might get in some vector quantity, what does this mean, simply $(-1*m)$ or is there an 'inverse' $m$ that can be found by the unary minus function $-(m)$?

Comment: @user37577 $-x$ defines the *opposite* of $x$,  $1/x$ is the *inverse* of $x$ (as frequency is the inverse of the period, $Hz = 1/s$). If you're measuring length, there is no negative length, as there is no negative mass. If you describe the physical space with a set of coordinates, it's possible that you have negative coordinates of the position of a point (e.g. using a Cartesian reference frame, with $x$-axis pointing to the right, the $y$-axis pointing upwards, all the points that lie at the left of $y$ axis have negative $x$-coord, e.g. $\mathbf{x}_P = - 3 m \mathbf{x} + 1 m \mathbf{y}$

Comment: This is part of my question, if $1m=m$ then does $-1m=-m$ (assume a negative position in a 1-dimensional frame and $-$ is unary minus.

Comment: you can say that, if you mean the measure of a coordinate (like $x_P$ in the example above), or the position of a point on a oriented line with a origin (and thus, again it's a coordinate along that line). It would be meaningless if you're measuring a length, since a length, like a distance, is non-negative. As I stated before, I would write the pure number -1 in front of the unit of measurement anyway, to avoid confusion

Comment: I believe so, It's just I see sometimes $1m$ and $m$ used interchangeably, for both vector and scalar quantities and it is confusing.

Comment: Hope it helped clarifying something. I think there is no much more to say about the argument

Comment: @user37577 Compare $1m = m$ and, let's say, $1 \cdot 8 = 8$, or even $2 \cdot 8 = 16$. It's the same kind of statement; i.e. the objects on the left and the right of "=" are not strictly speaking the same, but they *evaluate* to the same thing. IMO, it's best to think of $-m$ as shorthand for $-1 \cdot m$. Even though $m$, being a unit of length, can't conceptually be negative, thinking of it in the way described generalizes better: $-x$ is short for $-1 \cdot x$ (where x can take any value - positive, negative, or zero). And it fits with the $s \cdot x$ picture, where $s \in \mathbb  R$.

Comment: @user37577 Regarding the existence/definition of an inverse - that depends on the mathematical structure and the operation in question. E.g. for operation +, there's an additive inverse. Mathematicians might say smthing like, $b$ is the add. inv. of $a$ if $a + b = 0$ (this would be stated along with bunch of other definitions and properties). A multiplicative inverse would be $ab = 1$. But then you can notice that in this particular number system, multiplying by -1 gets you the additive inverse; once you establish that equivalence, you can also use "-x" as a label for "additive inverse of x".

Comment: Building on what @FilipMilovanović has said, dimensional analysis in general is a lot like doing algebra with a set of unknown variables, where the end result should be a single variable raised to some power (sometimes just 1) or a product of several variables raised to varying powers.